# how to solve object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{          
     richTextBox1.Clear();

     foreach (string line in richTextBox2.Lines)      
     {  

           string searchValue = line;
           searchValue = searchValue.Trim();
           dataGridView1.SelectionMode =DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            try
             {
              foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
               {
                if(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim().Equals(searchValue))//error containing line
                 {
                   richTextBox1.Text += (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim()) + "\n";
                 }
               }
             }
             catch (Exception exc)
             {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
             }
     }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It's a common error due to `null`, Could you please tell which line is throwing the error?

Comment: if(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim().Equals(searchValue))//error containing line

Comment: D.d.S Read the link @dotnetom gave you.

Comment: Use Convert.ToString() when you are not sure if source string will have valid value. So that even if you pass null it will not throw exception.

Comment: thank "dotnetkid". i done it. but error is still having..

Comment: thank you all of u. i solved my error.                                                     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
                         if(row.Cells[0].Value==null) {
                             break;
                         }
                           else
                         {
                             if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().TrimStart().TrimEnd().Equals(searchValue.TrimStart().TrimEnd()))
                           {
                                richTextBox1.Text += (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().TrimStart().TrimEnd()) + "\n";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)

{

if(row.Cells[0].Value==null) 
{

break;

} 
else {

if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().TrimStart().TrimEnd().Equals(searchValue.TrimStar‌​t().TrimEnd()))

{ richTextBox1.Text += (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().TrimStart().TrimEnd()) + "\n";}